# Are bars in Italy using pasta as straws?

Tags: europe, drinks, italy

It’s being reported in a lot of places that bars in Italy are using pasta as straws: [1](https://nypost.com/2019/10/09/pasta-straws-called-stroodles-spotted-at-bars-in-italy/) ,[2](https://www.boredpanda.com/pasta-straws-reduce-plastic-waste-italy-bars/), [3](https://www.unilad.co.uk/food/bars-in-italy-starting-to-use-pasta-straws-to-reduce-plastic-waste/), [4](https://educateinspirechange.org/popular/bars-in-italy-are-starting-to-use-pasta-straws-to-reduce-plastic-waste/).  They all cite the same source of a Reddit post [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/europe/comments/das9np/here_in_italy_bars_are_starting_to_use_pasta_as/), with a picture of one of these pasta straws in use. There is also a number of mentions to "Stroodles" which is a company that seems to make these kinds of straws [website here](https://stroodles.co.uk/). Is there any evidence other than this single picture that these straws are in use in Italy at all? Or has all of this media just seen a picture and run with it?

Comment: Not relevant to Italy, but I have been given pasta straws in several "trendy" bars in London. Unfortunately I am a Coeliac so had to return the drinks, and then drink the replacement straight from the glass like some sort of uncouth neanderthal ...

Comment: it _is_ tagged satire, fwiw

Comment: Not just Italy: here in Germany in our works canteen.

Comment: Also anecdotal evidence; I was in Italy last week, and got a paper straw once only. Otherwise the straws in my cocktails were always plastic.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Amazing-Pasta-Straw-Pack-000/dp/B07DW94M85

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, some bars in Italy are using pasta straws. But is it really surprising?

- [Civico5](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g1204396-d15056569-Reviews-Civico_5-Manduria_Province_of_Taranto_Puglia.html): Manduria, Italy

  - [Image](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g1204396-d15056569-Reviews-Civico_5-Manduria_Province_of_Taranto_Puglia.html#photos;aggregationId=&albumid=101&filter=7&ff=428404709)
  - [News](https://www.manduriaoggi.it/?news=43807): "Civico5 opta per le cannucce di pasta: un atto d'amore per l'ambiente" (*Civico5 opts for pasta straws: an act of love for the environment*)
- [Dum Dum Republic](https://www.facebook.com/DumDumRepublicPaestum/): Paestum, Italy

  - [Image](https://www.facebook.com/DumDumRepublicPaestum/photos/pb.70414083309.-2207520000.1570834729./10156741686548310/?type=3&theater)
  - [Blog](https://www.dumdumrepublic.com/blog/06/2019?id=149): "Sulla scia della sfida #plasticfree già lanciata attraverso la sostituzione delle cannucce con gli ziti, il Dum Dum Republic promuove, insieme a un gruppo di stabilimenti balneari e strutture ricettive locali, la rete Paestum Sea Life." (*In the wake of the challenge #plasticfree already launched through the replacement of straws with ziti, the Dum Dum Republic promotes, along with a group of beach resorts and local facilities, the Paestum Sea Life network.*)
- [Fly #Calaporto](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g635875-d4413305-Reviews-Fly_Calaporto-Polignano_a_Mare_Province_of_Bari_Puglia.html): Polignano a Mare Italy

  - [Image](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g635875-d4413305-Reviews-Fly_Calaporto-Polignano_a_Mare_Province_of_Bari_Puglia.html#photos;aggregationId=101&albumid=101&filter=7&ff=403949219)
  - [Review](https://www.tripadvisor.it/ShowUserReviews-g635875-d4413305-r697932580-Fly_Calaporto-Polignano_a_Mare_Province_of_Bari_Puglia.html): "Servizio lento,però il cibo era ottimo posto carino le cannucce di pasta erano inutili invece i camerieri sono molto gentili" (*Slow service, however the food was great nice place the pasta straws were useless instead the waiters are very nice*)
- [Sardigna Street Food](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g194949-d17391936-Reviews-Sardigna_Street_Food-Villasimius_Province_of_Cagliari_Sardinia.html): Villasimius, Sardinia Italy

  - [Image](https://www.tripadvisor.it/ShowUserReviews-g194949-d17391936-r692191595-Sardigna_Street_Food-Villasimius_Province_of_Cagliari_Sardinia.html#photos;geo=187879&detail=17391936&ff=420568556&albumViewMode=hero&aggregationId=101&albumid=101&baseMediaId=420568556&thumbnailMinWidth=50&cnt=30&offset=-1&filter=7&autoplay=)
  - [Review](https://web.archive.org/web/20191011214429/https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:wBSfxwHqoGYJ:https://www.tripadvisor.it/ShowUserReviews-g194949-d17391936-r692191595-Sardigna_Street_Food-Villasimius_Province_of_Cagliari_Sardinia.html+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us): "i vostri bimbi impazziranno per le cannucce di pasta!" (*your kids will go crazy for pasta straws!*)
- [Bevabbè](https://www.facebook.com/Bevabb%C3%A8-217997628375709/): Riccione, Italy

  - [Post](https://www.facebook.com/217997628375709/photos/a.263940807114724/1292857197556408/?type=3&theater): "Aderiamo al Romagna Plastic Free con questa geniale invenzione di @canu_organicpastastraw cannucce di pasta in versione senza glutine. Bevi senza plastica, bevi bene" (*We adhere to Romagna Plastic Free with this brilliant invention of @canu_organicpastastraw straws in a gluten-free version. Drink without plastic, drink well*)
- [Break Bar](https://www.facebook.com/BreakBarOstiglia): Ostiglia, Italy

  - [Images](https://www.facebook.com/BreakBarOstiglia/posts/379945742918197)

Searching the [news](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1440&bih=724&tbm=nws&q="Cannucce+di+pasta") for "cannucce di pasta" finds many more results and as a bonus they have better sources than posts marked "satire" on Reddit.

Comment: Guess the trick was to search in Italian rather than english